# How to fail CI of a PHP project on CRAP (Change Risk Anti-Pattern) threshold violation

Tags: php, continuous-integration

I’d like to monitor the CRAP (Change Risk Anti-Pattern) when running the CI pipelines.

I’d also like to be able to set a desired threshold.

My question is: how can I configure “something” to fail on CRAP threshold violation?

## What I tried

### 1. PHPUnit

PHPUnit measures the CRAP and reports it in the reports in many formats (it also has a dedicated crap4j report that can be generated).

Unfortunately I didn’t found any way to make the tests fail when maximum threshold of CRAP is exceeded.

### PHPMD and PHPDepends

The first one measures the Cyclomatic Complexity of code, but has’t any way to get code coverage reports as it doesn’t run any test.

Also, loading an externally created coverage report is [not planned nor desired](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/issues/45).

The same goes also for PHPDepend: no actual solution to calculate CRAP.

### Other solutions

Searching for a solution on Google, I found a plug-in for Jenkins, but I don’t use it

### How to do this?

I’m currently running my CI pipelines on GitHub Actions, but no solution seems to exist (and is also something that surprises me).

Any idea about how to make the CI pipeline fail on exceeding of a maximum threshold of CRAP?

(The solution I’m thinking about is to create a custom command to read the report from PHPUnit and do the checks, but I think a solution already exists)